# I have difficulty in removing the selected item in my Inventory GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, jscrollpane

I have a separate class for Items and an Inventory_MP class for the GUI. My task here is to remove the Item typed by the user and let it show in the interface that it has been removed. For some reason, I can't remove it. The error says:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)

```
if(e.getSource() == remButton){ 
        String delitem = nameField.getText();
            String delnum = numField.getText();
                    String delqty = qtyField.getText();
                    String delprice = priceField.getText();
                    Items v = new Items(delitem, delnum, Integer.parseInt(delqty), Double.parseDouble(delprice)); 
                    removeItems(delitem, delnum, delqty,delprice); 

public void removeItems(String delitem, String delnum, String delqty, String delprice){ 


                         Items v = new Items(); 
            itemModel.removeElementAt(itemCollection.indexOf(delitem)); //removes element in the JList
                        itemnumModel.removeElementAt(itemCollection.indexOf(delnum));
            qtyModel.removeElementAt(itemCollection.indexOf(delqty)); 
                        priceModel.removeElementAt(itemCollection.indexOf(delprice));  

            itemCollection.remove(searchItems(delitem)); //removes element in the arrayList
                    itemText.setText(" ");
            numText.setText(" ");
                        qtyText.setText(" "); 
                        priceText.setText(" "); 
                        window.validate();
                        window.repaint();   


                }
```

Comment: in the future, please include only the code that is erroring

Comment: I'm sorry >//< I'm only new. Here you go :)

Answer (score 0):

You're error is occurring on the Integer.parseInt call, it is because of the leading space at the front of your input string " 2".

```
String delqty = qtyField.getText();
```

`qtyField.getText();` is returning the string with a leading space. If you remove the space in qtyField it will fix this error, there may still be other errors in your code, but the call to Integer.parseInt will work fine.

Comment: Hello. I need the qty to be int because I will be calculating it in another method, unfortunately. :(

Comment: I am aware, and you are converting from a String to an int correctly by using the Integer.parseInt function, however this function will not work on a String that contains a leading space. Try doing this to eliminate the leading space ... `String delqty = (qtyField.getText()).substring(1);`

Comment: Thank you very much! I did that but I got an error saying StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 :(

Answer (score 0):

As said by ekcrisp, the error is due to `delqty` which contains a `' '`, and so can't be parse into `int`.

You can do some pretreatment on `delqty`. For example `delqty = delqty.replace(' ', '')` should do the trick in your case, however I suppose `qtyField` is a `JTextField` so the user can write anything. You will need a lots of pretreatment on `delqty`, or a smart user =)

Another solution should be to use the good Swing component, a [`JSlider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) or a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) may be more appropriate.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new at this. :( Where should I put the line `delqty = delqty.replace(' ', '');` and `String delqty = (qtyField.getText()).substring(1);` ? I'm sorry for being a noob sob :c

Comment: Don't be sorry, we were all noobs, and we all learn everyday :) You have to put one (not the both) line between `String delqty = qtyField.getText();` and the first `Integer.parseInt(delqty)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) I did that and I got an error saying StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 :(

Comment: This error come from `substring(1)`... Use only `delqty = delqty.replace(' ', '')`

Comment: I did that too :( but there's another error (darrrrnnnn T^T) saying "empty character literal and unclosed character literal"

Comment: Some general advice, it is a good idea to test smaller segments of your code as you are programming them, this helps prevent this kind of thing from happening, where errors keep popping up and it's especially difficult to find and fix them. Helps nip errors in the bud so to speak

Comment: also keep track of the line numbers your errors happen on, this tells you exactly where the program went awry and will narrow down your search greatly